# Check if an object is a type of a generic type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I understand that TypeScript works as static type checker that transpiles to Javascript.

So if I want to do something like the following, is there any workaround?

```
const resolve = <T>(map): T => {
    for (const value of map) {
        if (value instanceof T) {
            return <T> value;
        }
    }

    return null;
};

const map = [new A(), new B()];
const a = resolve<A>(map);
const b = resolve<B>(map);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to perform runtime checks based on the class you will need to pass it in as an argument to the function, just setting the type argument won't do since that will be erased during compilation:

```
const resolve = <T>(map: any[], ctor: new (...a: any) => T): T | null => {
    for (const value of map) {
        if (value instanceof ctor) {
            return <T> value;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
class A{}
class B{}

const map = [new A(), new B()];
const a = resolve(map, A);
const b = resolve(map, B);
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUwiANgNwTAvDAPAFQD4AKAWwEMAHALhnLAE8BtAXQBoZgoQ5awEA7jGIA6MeVr0GASmyEY+abXwwAPjDABXFCjkwA3gCgYJmADMew0JFhpyKTZhBmYFSrKOmvMAJYvidg6YPjb0wAjOCh7G3rGIUJpwYHhEMIGOANwxsQC+2TB5XvGJyVo6WXnAKOQQEDAAgvqV1bUwAEJNhobW0K5U2DBM-EL1xNIcw+1jLFk9sOQDiMjoCGRUHPXSs+C9AEaLSKgYa5QcbVtAA)

Comment: This compiles - if you use "if (value instanceof ctor) {"

Comment: @TonyRietwyk yeah. That was an oversight. My bad